# Is "i.e." OK for the academic paper?

Tags: writing

I'm writing an academic paper in computer science field.

Is "i.e." permissible for a formal document like an academic papaer?

I hope to write a sentence such as the following:

> The output of the machine "y1" is utilized as the input of the next machine "x2", i.e. "x2=y1".

What I hope to say is

- the machine 1 output "y1".
- the machine 2 get "y1" as its input "x2".
- That means "x2 = y1"

Comment: "i.e." is not out of place in academic writing. You could also the English term instead of the Latin abbreviation: _The output of the machine "y1" is utilized as the input of the next machine "x2", that is: "x2=y1"._

Comment: If you are submitting an academic paper, you will almost certainly be given stylistic guidelines; universities and journals will either have their own style manual or use an [established style](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/2579) (e.g. APA, CSE, MLA), which may provide guidance on the use of Latin, abbreviations, and/or Latin abbreviations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *is* used in academic writing. Both [APA](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2011/02/changes-parentheses-bring.html) and [MLA](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/747/11/) let you use *i.e.*, but you will want to follow whatever style guide you're supposed to. You can ask your advisor about this.

I found a random paper that uses *i.e.*, as an example. [*Geometric Modeling Using Octree Encoding*](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0146664X82901046) (emphasis mine):

> Objects may be concave or convex, have holes (including interior holes), consist of disjoint parts, and possess sculptured (**i.e.,** “free-form”) surfaces.

Comment: Note that APA only permits "i.e.", "e.g." and so on, *inside brackets*